# ReactImageView set Bitmap source

Tags: android, react-native, android-bitmap, fresco

I have a rather strange situation where I want to display images in React-Native coming from a native library in bitmap form. In order to get the Bitmap object that needs to be rendered, the component needs to make use of an "adId" prop.

I thus far have the following code for a native component:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
import com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageView;

public class AdIconViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<ReactImageView> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCTAdIconView";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    public ReactImageView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
        return new ReactImageView(context, Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder(), null, null);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "adId")
    public void setAdId(ReactImageView view, String adId) {
        final Bitmap icon = AppodealModule.getIcon(adId);
        // What now?
    }
}
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to set the bitmap source of the ReactImageView. ReactImageView is completely undocumented but seems to use Fresco (which I don't know at all). Is there some way I can use some other DraweeControllerBuilder to provide Bitmaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresco manages the bitmap cache itself thus it might be more convenient to use getIconUrl and set an URL instead of bitmap, using this guide - http://frescolib.org/docs/using-simpledraweeview.html

If you want to use bitmap itself these docs can give you a vision of the fresco pipeline - http://frescolib.org/docs/using-image-pipeline.html